# Drupal captcha with boost module

Tags: captcha

I use boost module and now I want to use captcha to prevent spam comments. These two module works with each other successfuly?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the CAPTCHA module disables Drupal page caching. And as Boost provides static page caching for increasing performance, these two modules will not work correctly together. So what are the options to prevent spam while using page caching? There are several ways to solve this problem:

1. Use CAPTCHA and make comments on a separate form. In order to do this make the following steps:

1)  go to admin/content/types

2)  Click the edit link for the page, blog entry, or other type you want to modify

3)  In the Comment Settings find “Location of Comment Submission Form”

4)  Select the "Display on separate page" option and save content type.

You can do this with each content type which is displayed often enough to decrease performance.

2.   Use Mollom which is a great solution for all spam problems and make sure it is set in the following way:
Protection mode: Text analysis
When text analysis identifies spam: Automatically discard the post.
Also, see other alternatives to CAPTCHA module for spam prevention on Drupal websites [here](http://www.blog.qarea.com/web-development/8-drupal-modules-to-complete-spam-protection/).

3.   Use Boost Captcha which is a new module allowing boost caching of Drupal pages with forms with CAPTCHA.